# Appending date to file name in Send Mail Task Editor of SSIS

Tags: ssis

In the Send Mail Task Editor I added a FileAttachments property in the Expressions section with the following value:

```
"C:\\ImportedProjects\\WeeklyStatus_XXXRules_" + 
(DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv"
```

I am needing to append the date to my attached file because this package will be executed daily that sends this attached file in an email to the recipients. However, I'm getting this error and need help on how to create a new file each time without having the file already exist in the file location:

```
Error at SendWeeklyStatus_XXXRules[Send Mail Task]:Either the file `"C:\ImportedProjects\WeeklyStatus_XXXRules_20150901.csv" does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the file.`
```

In addition, the Flat File Connection Manager in the data flow that is executed prior to this also has this same definition in its Expression property.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the flatfile created in the same dataflow as the email? Personally I prefer to set up the file path / file name and the glue-on date as separate variables as this allows me to alter file path and filename in the config file. Do you still get the same error if ignore the email part (for the moment) but use a file system object to copy/rename/move the file (using its variable name) after all other processes have completed?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem.  Just in case anyone has the same issue here are the steps I took:

1. Modified the Flat File Connection Manager to use the same dynamic file name and create the file.
2. In the Send Mail Task set the DelayedValidation to True in the properties and it found the file without issue and sent it successfully.

That was it.  Thanks.